# Zend_Db_Expr not working

Tags: mysql, macos, zend-framework

I am trying to use `Zend_Db_Expr` in my installation ZF1 on my Mac.  This works in production, but doesn't work on my Mac.  Our production server is running MySQL 5.1 and my Mac is running 5.6.  Has something changed with MySQL that it doesn't allow `Zend_Db_Expr` to work with later versions of MySQL?

I've tried using both `new Zend_DB_Expr('NULL')` and both `new Zend_Db_Expr('NOW')` and `new Zend_Db_Expr('NOW()')` and neither works.  (I believe the latter is correct.  Does anyone have any insight as to why this is happening.

I don't know whether it's because I'm on a Mac or it's just changes in MySQL.  I'd appreciate any help.  The error I get is `Incorrect datetime value: 'NOW()' for column 'date_closed'` But also `Incorrect datetime value: 'NOW' for column 'date_closed'`

```
$arrData['internal_review_date']        = $this->getRequest()->getPost('internal_review_date','0000-00-00 00:00:00');
            if ($arrData['internal_review_date'] != '0000-00-00 00:00:00') {
                $arrData['internal_review_date'] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($arrData['internal_review_date']));
            }
            $arrData['desired_launch_date']        = $this->getRequest()->getPost('desired_launch_date','0000-00-00 00:00:00');
            if ($arrData['desired_launch_date'] != '0000-00-00 00:00:00') {
                $arrData['desired_launch_date'] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($arrData['desired_launch_date']));
            }
            $arrData['submitted_by']         = trim($this->getRequest()->getPost('submitted_by'));
            $arrData['approved_by']          = trim($this->getRequest()->getPost('approved_by'));
            $arrData['approval_date']        = $this->getRequest()->getPost('approval_date','0000-00-00 00:00:00');
            if ($arrData['approval_date'] != '0000-00-00 00:00:00') {
                $arrData['approval_date'] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($arrData['approval_date']));
            }
            $arrData['myriad_notes']        = $this->getRequest()->getPost('myriad_notes');
            $arrData['approved_by']          = trim($this->getRequest()->getPost('approved_by'));
            $arrData['request']              = trim($this->getRequest()->getPost('request'));
            $arrData['objective']            = trim($this->getRequest()->getPost('objective'));
            $arrData['additional_info']      = trim($this->getRequest()->getPost('additional_info'));
            $arrData['study_club']           = (int) $this->getRequest()->getPost('study_club');
            $arrData['digital_campus']       = (int) $this->getRequest()->getPost('digital_campus');
            $arrData['case_assistant']       = (int) $this->getRequest()->getPost('case_assistant');
            $arrData['faculty_club']         = (int) $this->getRequest()->getPost('faculty_club');
            $arrData['spear_review']         = (int) $this->getRequest()->getPost('spear_review');
            $arrData['spear_talk']           = (int) $this->getRequest()->getPost('spear_talk');
            $arrData['admin']                = (int) $this->getRequest()->getPost('admin');
            $arrData['other']                = (int) $this->getRequest()->getPost('other');
            $arrData['request_status']       = $this->getRequest()->getPost('request_status', 'Active');
            if ($arrData['request_status'] == 'Completed') {
                $arrData['date_closed'] = new Zend_Db_Expr('NOW');
            } else {
                $arrData['date_closed'] = '0000-00-00 00:00:00';
            }


....
 $objWebsite = new Website_Requests();
if ($intId == 0) {
                    $arrData['date_created'] = new Zend_Db_Expr('NOW()');
                    $intId = $objWebsite->insert($arrData);
                    $this->_helper->FlashMessenger(array('success' => 'The Website Request Form has been submitted successfully.'));
                } else {
                    $arrData['date_updated'] = new Zend_Db_Expr('NOW()');
                    $strWhere = $objWebsite->getAdapter()->quoteInto('id = ?', $intId);
                    $objWebsite->update($arrData, $strWhere);
                    $this->_helper->FlashMessenger(array('success' => 'The Website Request Form has been updated successfully.'));
                }
```

Comment: Can you provide a little context on how you are using the class? What query generates that error?

Comment: I'm trying to run an update on an existing row in the DB

Comment: All it does is update the row.  If I use date('Y-m-d H:i:s') it works.

Comment: Could you update your question to include the relevant part of that code?

Comment: This:  `$arrData['date_closed'] = new Zend_Db_Expr('NOW')` is what throws the error.

Comment: This is the SQL I used to create the field: `ALTER TABLE tbl_website_requests ADD date_closed DATETIME AFTER approval_date`

Comment: No, interestingly enough.

Comment: Which base class is `Website_Requests` a member of?

Comment: It's a custom class.  Everything works fine but the one line.  It's not the class.  If I changed the line in question to date(...), it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting.  What I had to do was move the section in question to the update call.  Like this:

```
if ($intId == 0) {
                    $arrData['date_created'] = new Zend_Db_Expr('NOW()');
                    $intId = $objWebsite->insert($arrData);
                    $this->_helper->FlashMessenger(array('success' => 'The Website Request Form has been submitted successfully.'));
                } else {
                    $arrData['date_updated'] = new Zend_Db_Expr('NOW()');
                    if ($arrData['request_status'] == 'Completed') {
                        $arrData['date_closed'] = new Zend_Db_Expr('NOW()');
                    } else {
                        $arrData['date_closed'] = '0000-00-00 00:00:00';
                    }
                    $strWhere = $objWebsite->getAdapter()->quoteInto('id = ?', $intId);
                    $objWebsite->update($arrData, $strWhere);
                    $this->_helper->FlashMessenger(array('success' => 'The Website Request Form has been updated successfully.'));
                }
```